# help me to debug file packed with molebox and proteced with obsidium

Tags: debugging, unpacking

I have a exe file that packed with molebox and protected with obsidium.

[image]

I try to unpack it with demoleition but it has some problem. when I want to open the unpacked file
it says "Component 'ImpulseAniLabel.ocx' or one of its dependencies not correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid".
After that I try to open it with x32dbg and debug it.
But I couldn't change any assembly code. I mean that when I change an assembly code and patch the file, it will be the same of the first code. There is not any changing in the codes. It won't do any changing.

Comment: Well the issue with the ActiveX component (.ocx) could either mean demoleition needs it or that your executable got to run during the unpacking attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the answer.
You can use the "demoleition" software in order to unpack these file that packed with "MoleBox" or "Obsidium".

Comment: How is this an answer? In the question you clearly state that your unpacking attempt failed. You even describe an error. So _something_ has to have happened between question and answer for it to succeed now. Please add that to your answer and accept the answer, because that's what this site is about.